# Documents / Library missing after migrating My Site to the new Content Database

Tags: document-library, powershell, my-site, content-database

I've moved some My Sites to new content database with the powershell cmdlet Move-SPSite. However, after moving them, it appears documents were "lost" on some of them (most of sites is just fine). When I'm browsing content database itself with SQL Manager, I can see all the (missing) documents. However, they simply don't appear on the portal. In fact, the whole "Personal Document" library is not there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Perhaps the permissions were messed up during the move. Have you tried access the my site's personal documents library with a farm admin account?

Comment: @PhilGreer SP2010, it was done under Evelated privileges and I tried access files with admin account

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure that you can access one of those inaccessible "Personal Documents" libraries and its items via powershell:

```
$mysitelist = (get-spweb http://mysite/personal/user_name).Lists["Personal Documents"]
$mysitelist.items
```

If you can access the list items, use powershell to inherit library permissions from the site with:

```
$mysitelist.ResetRoleInheritance()
$mysitelist.Update()
```

A variant of this is among some of the suggestions in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a77e8233-073f-4c22-ad1a-8c872cf84f82/users-denied-access-to-shared-documents-and-private-documents-libraries-in-mysite?forum=sharepointadminprevious). If the above approach does not work, consider some of the other ideas in that thread.

**Edit**

If you can't access the Personal Documents libraries via powershell, then they were not copied across properly with move-spsite.

If you still have access to the original site collections, try exporting and importing the libraries with `export-spweb` and `import-spweb`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see library via PowerShell.

Comment: @StupidOne I updated my answer with more info. Let me know if export/import works for you.